# New FB UI element promote/demote does what

Tags: javascript, facebook, user-interface

iOS Facebook app on iPhone X

I’ve never seen this before. Up and down arrows (wedges, really) beside comments that keep a count of upvotes and downvotes like stackoverflow. The total, an integer number, is shown between the wedges.

I cannot find Any notice or documentation about this feature. Is it new? How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

I just came upon this new feature as well. I was testing it out and I can’t get it back to 0. I demoted first making -1, then promoted, wanted it back to 0, but it changed to 1. ‍♂️ So dumb.

Comment: What is the emoji and male symbol have to do with this answer?